# One Facebook account on Two domains

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I’m using Facebook login and share on my website.

Now I have at second website, and I want to use the same Facebook for developers account / App.

I want to show the information from the different website.

Is it possible to have to domains on one Facebook for developers? Or is there a workaround on this?

I using HTML5 with AngularJS on the client and C# MVC 5 back end.

Could I change the Facebook for developers account / App Id back end in StartUp.Auth by looking on the calling domain? Then I just have to create a new Facebook App.

Comment: Facebook only allows one domain. If the domains have to do with each other you have have them redirect to the same domain and do login there. If they have nothing to do with each other you should use two different apps

Comment: Thanks. It runs on the same machine, and the code change views dynamicly for each domain. That I need to find a workaround for

Comment: I already told you what to do

Comment: Thanks. I will fix it like that